# Let $f: G \to H$ be a homomorphism and let $|G| = 10$ and $|H| = 4$ Prove that $f$ is not onto.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have no idea how to this. Is there a theorem that I wasn't taught that says homomorphism can not be onto but still a homomorphism? Any suggestions on how to approach this question? According to the Pinter the lines around $G$ and $H$ represent order of a group.

Comment: *Hint:* Use [First Isomorphism Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#First_isomorphism_theorem), and [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)).

Comment: But I don't know what the kernel is. Although Lagrange's Theorem would make sense here :) thank you for the hint I appreciate it :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $N$ is the kerel of $f$. Then $G/N\cong H$. But then $o(G/N)=o(H)=4$, but then $4$ divides $10$, where we arrive at a contradiction.